# Not able to edit date in HTML5 date control

Tags: html, date

```
document.getElementById("appealTriggerDate").valueAsDate = vm.appealEntity.DateOfAppealTrigger();
```

I am using above line of code to display date in HTML5 date control. After I do this, I find that I am unable to edit date from the date control. The control does not set the date selected.

```
Fri Nov 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500(Eastern Standard Time)
```

vm.appealEntity.DateOfAppealTrigger() returns date in above format. The date is as fetched from the database. I am not doing any formatting.

If I try to set the date in the format below, I can see the date set in the control, but edit it still not possible.

```
 var dt= new Date(vm.appealEntity.DateOfAppealTrigger());
        var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = dt.getDate();
        if (month < 10)
            month = "0" + month;
        if (day < 10)
            day = "0" + day;

        document.getElementById("appealTriggerDate").value = dt.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Comment: Which library are you using and/or what does the `DateOfAppealTrigger` method return?

Comment: Are there any error messages shown in the console?

Comment: There are no error messages and the control does set the right date.

Comment: `.valueAsDate` expects a date object. What you have looks like a string.